# Xcode Swift 4 Remove matched objects in 2 arrays?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode

i have 2 Arrays of same objects class , both arrays has common objects , how i can find this objects and remove them ?

Array A :

- class.object.a
- class.object.b
- class.object.c

Array B :

- class.object.b
- class.object.c

Array C = A-B

- class.object.a

i have tried to do this , but Xcode telling me missing Where in contains !

```
 let newArray  = allTracks.filter { !_allObjects.contains($0.song_name) }
```

Answer (score 0):

arrayA - arrayB = arrayC

```
let arrayA = ["a","b","c"]
let arrayB = ["a","x","z"]
let arrayC = arrayA.filter({item in !arrayB.contains(item)})

print(arrayC) //["b", "c"]
```

Comment: they array u have provided is array of strings , my question is same but with array's of objects

Answer (score 0):

make this:

```
 NSMtableArray has a function : .removeObject(identicalTo: yourObject).
```

so you crate your arryC removing object that are the same. you can make this in a for each loop, or while loop

Comment: my goal is to remove them without looping